# Does American citizen need a Visa for Tahiti

Tags: visas

I know that an American passport holder does not require a visa to visit France for a short vacation. Does that hold good if one was visiting Tahiti  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tahiti tourist visa is not required for citizens of United States for a stay up to 90 days.

Source: [VisaHQ](http://tahiti.visahq.com/)